# Memcached is not launching

Tags: linux, redhat, boot, memcached, start

I just installed memcached and the memcache pecl extension. Now randomly I cannot get it to start. When I run `service memcached start` I get this:

```
Starting memcached: chown: `memcached\r': invalid user
 to switch toe user memcached
 [FAILED]
```

What is going on? As far as I know, I performed the installation correctly. In fact, it was running fine but must have randomly stopped...? Im running RedHat x86_64 es5.

EDIT: maybe I am doing this wrong. What command do I need to run to check if memcached is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first make sure you have the memcache user

```
id memcached
```

you have an error in your config.. looks like a dos line breaks.. Run the following command over the memcache sysconfig script

```
dos2unix /etc/sysconfig/memcached
```

Comment: dos2unix resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

How did you install memcached?

You should be able to run:

```
service memcached status
```

or

```
lsof -i :11211
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep memcache
```

to see if it's running.

Cheers